# Django-Admin custom ImageField

Tags: django, admin, imagefield

I wanna add additional `ImageField` which obtains image from `static` folder to the model. I've tried to use some answers from the same questions, but there aren't anything about `ImageField`.

Comment: create a profile model, and add image field to i and then create a one to one relationship between the user and profile

Comment: No, that is not what I was trying. I needed to reflect some specific default image(It's hard to explain), but I-ve already figured out how to make it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### [SOLUTION]

#### I've found some way to load image via `def`

```py
# admin.py

@admin.register(Course)
class CourseAdmin(..., admin.ModelAdmin):
...
readonly_fields = [..., 'headshot_certic_preview_image', ]
fieldsets = (
... ,
('Image info', {
            'fields': ('image', ('image_courses_and_course', 'image_dash'),
                       ('certic_preview_image', 'first_row_course_name', 'second_row_course_name',
                        'headshot_certic_preview_image'),
                       ),
        }),
...
     )
def headshot_certic_preview_image(self, obj):
        return mark_safe('<img src="{url}" width="{width}" height={height} />'.format(
            url=os.path.join('media/', obj.certic_preview_image.url),
            width=700,
            height=516
        ))
```